# auto increment Concat string variable and integer variable

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, concatenation

i want to String like This "Campaign A-1" to "Campaign A-4" after That i want String Change to "Campaign B-1" to "Campaign B-4" and Last stage is "Campaign Z-1" to "Campaign Z-4"..
AND String "Campaign Alpabhet-Number" Auto increment. Not Enter by User.
this 
Please Tell me how to create Condition for this

This is my Code:
[See CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITu5g.jpg)

This is Output:
[See OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9yTz.jpg)

Please Help me
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please edit the question with your code instead of posting an image. Refer to [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Is this data restricted to a single phone? Or will it be pushed to a server? If it's communal data you should generate IDs on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat chars in Java just like an int, allowing you to increment the char until your desired stopping point.

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    char character = 'A'; // start with a

    while ( character <= 'Z' ) { // stop after character is Z
        for ( int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ) {
            strings.add( String.format( "Campaign %c-%d", character, i ) );
        }
        character++; // increment character
    }

    strings.forEach( System.out::println );
```

Comment: Great solution, lovely.

Comment: It seems unlikely the OP wants to generate all the codes upfront; I would guess you need to track the last used id and produce new ids on demand like a generator.

Comment: Could also generate all the codes up front and just keep track of the current position in the list 

Comment: You're right; I should put different ideas into a different answer, not convert/corrupt your answer!

Answer (score 0):

## Generator (On-Demand)

You can generate IDs on-demand for any 'position' in your sequence:

```
public class IdGenerator {
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 4; // 'unit' column is base 4

    public static String generate(int position) {
        int quotient = position / MAX_NUMBER;
        int remainder = position % MAX_NUMBER;

        return String.format(
                "Campaign %c-%d",
                (char) (quotient + 'A'),
                remainder + 1
        );
    }
}
```

Test (for real-world use just store the current position in a db; same for all answers):

```
// Calculate & print all IDs
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26 * 4; i++) { // position is 0-based
        System.out.println(generate(i));
    }
}

// Campaign A-1
// ...
// Campaign Z-4
```